# Modular Raspberry Pi Model

Tags: modules

Is there a modular, interchangeable (phone-blocks like) tiny computer out there ?
I'd like to add and remove stuff from my computer when the processor becomes old for example. I know raspberry pi has no such device, maybe you know one ? 
The [Olimex](https://olimex.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/a20-olinuxino-lime2-now-with-pcb-revision-g/) is quite famous and open hardware so it makes it easier to change stuff but I would like something better.

Comment: Swap out the processor when it becomes old? You do understand that the RPi is an SoC right?

Comment: -1 for obviously not even attempting to check with the raspberry pi foundation or even googling your issue.

Comment: You want to swap out the processor down the road *on a $35 device*?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there's not - a fact that a quick look on the rather short list of models of the Raspberry Pi would reveal. I'd also assume that the intended audience of the Pi and the targeted cost structure of the board are prohibitive to this approach.

Interchangeable however are all the "non-essential" peripherals given the variety of modules provided by the RPi Foundation and third parties.

Answer (score -2):

However there are several different types of Raspberry Pi, which you may upgrade or downgrade to if you so desire.

Comment: This is just completely wrong.  There is not a single model of the RPi that is modifiable in any way.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I think the idea was "upgrade the whole Pi".  That's pretty much the one avenue available for upgrades with a RasPi.